# Makefile C++11 errors on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, makefile

I have written an application in the IDE CLion. I am trying to create a Makefile on a Linux machine. I used a template Makefile to create my own Makefile, however, there are issues. Note that there are 3 classes called quote, trade and signal.

```
CXX = g++
# mandatory build flags
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -Werror -std=c++11

# mandatory link flags
AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-as-neeeded

output: main.o quote.o trade.o signal.o
    ${CXX} ${AM_LDFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@

%: %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${AM_CXXFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $< -c -o $@

quote.o: quote.cpp quote.h
trade.o: trade.cpp trade.h
signal.o: signal.cpp signal.h
```

When I run the Makefile, I get the errors:

error: #error This file required the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Then, many errors appear which require C++11 support. For example, there are issues with `std::string`, `std::chrono`. How do I fix this? I am requesting that someone fix the code. Since I just started learning MakeFile today, I most likely won't understand your technical suggestion. Please help. Very appreciative!

EDIT: After following the suggestions below, I fixed the above error. I am now getting the following errors:

> > > > g++ -02 -Werror -std=c++11  -c -o main.o main.cpp
> > > >
> > > > g++ -02 -Werror -std=c++11  -c -o quote.o quote.cpp
> > > >
> > > > g++ -02 -Werror -std=c++11  -c -o trade.o trade.cpp
> > > >
> > > > g++ -Wl, -as-needed main.o quote.o trade.o signal.o -o output
> > > >
> > > > /usr/bin/ld: unrecognixed -a option 's-needed'
> > > >
> > > > collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to the CXXFLAGS...

Comment: @DanMašek Could you explicitly write exactly how this is done?

Comment: something like `CXXFLAGS = -O2 -Werror -std=c++11` instead of the existing line you have there.

Comment: @DanMašek I did exactly as you stated, but the same errors persist.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that the appropriate parameter would already get passed in through `AM_CXXFLAGS`. The problem is somewhere else. Can you post the console output of the entire build?

Comment: Show us the full output from running `make` not just the error message.

Comment: @Etan Reisner Please see my edits for the error message

Comment: That's an entirely different error then the one you said you were getting. Do you still get the other error? Or did you fix that and just not report the new error?

Comment: @Etan Reisner I fixed the other error by following Sam's suggestion below. I didn't report the current error in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AM_CXXFLAGS` is used by `automake`. You are not using `automake`, so this accomplishes nothing.

Put all your compiler flags into `CXXFLAGS` only.

Comment: Works for me just fine.

Comment: thanks! I still receive other messages. Could you please see my edits above?

Comment: You made a typo in the option's name. Reread ld's manual page, and fix your typo.